# tuples and list arrangements in python

Tags: python

These fours 'teams' consequently did total number of 'goals':

```
teams = ['W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']
goals = [4, 5, 1, 9]
```

Now, how to know which team did following goals?

```
given_goals = [3, 2, 7, 15]
```

The expected answer should be in this form:

```
answers = [('W', (2, 3)),
           ('X', 7),
           ('Z', 15)]
```

`W` made 4 consecutive goals therefore the 2nd and 3rd goal is theirs.
Then `X` made 5 consecutive goals (5-10) after `W` so goal number 7 is theirs and so on.

I tried but it seems difficult way:

```
teams_ = [team for team, goal in zip(teams, goals) for g in range(goal)]

teams_goals = [teams_[g-1] for g in given_goals]
print teams_goals
```

Is there an easier way?

Comment: How are you getting 2 and 3 for W? W is 4 no? 2+3 is 5? Could you provide some additional examples or the problem statement?

Comment: @BAH because W did 4 consecutive goals. So, second and third goal belongs to W.

Comment: I think it's basically goals 2, 3 are still within the range of 4 goals, so W scored them. Then X scored 5 more goals (making the range 9), which means X scored the 7th goal overall, and so forth.

Comment: @BAH exactly, thanks

Comment: Based off your own answer, this almost gets us there, but I'd need to import `defaultdict` to get it to the format you want, and it seems that we can only use builtins: `teams_and_total_goals = ''.join(team*goal for team, goal in zip(teams, goals))`

Comment: `print([(teams_and_total_goals[x], x) for x in given_goals])` (continuing in the next comment for readability). @jean

Comment: This prints `[('W', 3), ('W', 2), ('X', 7), ('Z', 15)]`

Comment: I do like @Bharel's answer though, why reinvent the wheel using only builtins if you have a module like `itertools` (I've gotten used to assuming that others are smarter than me, so my implementation is probably going to be worse than theirs).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's the most efficient way I believe:

```
import bisect
import itertools

teams = ['W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']
goals = [4, 5, 1, 9]

# Create the max goal of each team
goal_ranges = itertools.accumulate(goals)

# Create sorted tuples of goals and teams (comes sorted because of accumulate)
ordered_teams = list(zip(goal_ranges, teams))

def get_team(goal_number):
    # Get the leftmost occurence of the goal number, and extract the team from the tuple
    return ordered_teams[bisect.bisect_left(ordered_teams, (goal_number,))][1]
```

Comment: I want to solve it without importing such things which is more difficult.

Comment: @jean importing `bisect` and `itertools` is very common. It's part of the built-in standard library. I can help writing a second answer but this is a very efficient way I believe. Think of it as using any other built-in like `map()` or `zip()` (Which `itertools` has an implementation of btw)

Comment: upvoted but I would expect your second answer for accepting, thanks.

Comment: +1, I've used the `itertools` module a lot, but never really used `accumulate`; and I've never even heard of `bisect` till now.